# Weeknum function is not working correctly

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I got an issue using DAX function. The thing is that I'm using a dataset and I need to caclulate the date using weeks but unfortunately I can't find it directly. 
So, I have created a new measure and I tried to apply the function below :
Week Number = WEEKNUM(Table1[Date],2)

And this give me the following error :
"A single value for column 'Date' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

The structure of my file is like this:

```
DATE        N° PAGE 
26/06/2018  E2  17
27/06/2018  E6  59  
28/06/2018  E7  179 
29/06/2018  E8  223
30/06/2018  E11 205 
01/07/2018  F13 202
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem having to do with the `WEEKNUM` function, but has to do with the difference between a measure and a calculated column.

If you are creating a **calculated column** then your formula should work because DAX uses the row context to know which single date to use in the calculation.

If you are creating a **measure** then it is not associated with any single row, so you need to specify an aggregate so it has a single date value to work with.

---

Reference: [Calculated columns and measures in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/)